# Remove single product tabs and add the related content instead In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I have a client who wants to pull the information that defaults into tabs on single product pages in WooCommerce into a different location on the page and remove the tabs entirely.

There are three default product tabs:

- product Description,
- Additional Information
- and Reviews.

Removing the tabs and setting up the Description to display was easy enough to set up in 
`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );

function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 10 );
```

That works fine.

I tried to repeat the process by building out new functions that access the template files for **Additional Info** and **Reviews** like so:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_addinfo() {
  woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_addinfo', 20 );

function woocommerce_template_product_reviews() {
  woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/review-rating.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_reviews', 30 );
```

But neither is displaying. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First `woocommerce_get_template()` is deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_template()` instead. After some searching and testing *(mainly to get the reviews displayed)*, I have found the way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'removing_product_tabs', 2 );
function removing_product_tabs(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'get_product_tab_templates_displayed', 10 );
}
function get_product_tab_templates_displayed() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
    comments_template();
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and work *(WC 3+)*.

Comment: That does it -- my thanks to you for this and for cleaning up my question.

Comment: @jimiayler You are welcome … It was not so easy to find out… but now it works :)

Comment: Agreed on the difficulty of trying to achieve this kind of basic re-configuring of WooCommerce's UI -- other platforms are much more transparent in this regard.

Comment: It works! As wc_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' ); didn't when unsetting the reviews tab!