# Change WooCommerce Single Product Description Output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Another newbie WooCommerce question I haven't been able to track down online. I am accessing what displays by default in the **Description** tab on single product pages in WooCommerce and placing that markup elsewhere on the page. But where that markup is being generated and how to change the output is not clear to me. Here's a truncated example of what is output from the template `single-product/tabs/description.php`:

```
<div class="single-product-content">
Lorem ipsum blah blah blah...
<div class="row ksps">...</div>
<div class="related products">...</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is remove that "Lorem ipsum" text (which I'm assuming is  the long description for the product) that immediately follows the parent div with the class `single-product-content`. I've tried CSS hacks like making `single-product-content` have a visibility of "collapse" and then make the child divs "visible". That displays them but, of course, leaves a sizable gap before the div with the classes `row ksps`. Besides, that's a hack -- I should be able to access whatever is constructing that Description output. In the template `single-product/tabs/description.php`, there's simply this otherwise mysterious final line:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

What is driving that and how can I tease out the text from being added before the child divs? Thanks for your help here.

Comment: None that should be relevant to this question. I added the code you suggested to the file `wp-content\themes\vg-ebuilder\woocommerce/woocommerce-functions.php`. I made no changes at all to descriptions.php. This only serves to reinforce my question: what is driving the construction of `<?php the_content(); ?>`? That should tell us where this errant text (again, that appears to be the long description) is coming from.

Comment: BTW, referring to a separate discussion @LoicTheAztec assisted me with before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196441/remove-single-product-tabs-and-add-the-related-content-instead-in-woocommerce

Comment: :) That was for everyone else, not you -- that why I said you had assisted me before. I didn't think you had forgotten! Let's see if someone else has a suggestion. Thanks again.